# How to work Facebook Messenger bot generic template sharable

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

What happens to the actual messenger in the `sharable` feature?

I can not understand the change in the native share button (both PC and mobile).

I would like to know what the `sharable` setting changes.

There is no change in setting values (see image).

[image]

Sample request:

```
 {
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"generic",
        ***"sharable":true or false,***
        "elements":[
           {
            "title":"Welcome to Peter\'s Hats",
            "image_url":"https://petersfancybrownhats.com/company_image.png",
            "subtitle":"We\'ve got the right hat for everyone.",
            "buttons":[
              {
                "type":"web_url",
                "url":"https://petersfancybrownhats.com",
                "title":"View Website"
              },{
                "type":"postback",
                "title":"Start Chatting",
                "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
              }              
            ]      
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self solved.

If the button type of the element button is postback or share, sharable does not work.

Comment: Hey, I'm struggling with this as well. Could you dig a little deeper? How did you solved it? You have two buttons, neither of their types is allowed to be postback of sharable? Or do I have to create a dedicated button for sharing?
Could you provide your working code? Many thanks in advance!